# Как запретить разрешение: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Я написал небольшой калькулятор на Xamarin Forms. В манифесте убрал все разрешения, так как они не нужны для работы приложения. Однако App Bundle Explorer в консоли разработчика показывает, что приложение требует следующие разрешения:

```
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Подобноя информация о требуемом разрешении стоит и в Google Play.

Вот данные манифеста:

```
versionCode=19
versionName=1.1.8
installLocation=auto
minSdkVersion=21
targetSdkVersion=30
```

Как убрать эти ненужные разрешения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение можно найти по следующей ссылке: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4662

1. Создайте новый проект Xamarin Android
2. Установите для свойства AndroidManifestMerger значение manifestmerger.jar в файле csproj.
3. Добавьте в AndroidManifest.xml <manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools”, а затем атрибут 'tools: node = "remove"'.

Пример:

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools: node = "remove"/>
```

4. Создайте приложение.